# Whats the Regular Expression (regex) for searching within brackets {} only

Tags: css, regex, search, replace, sass

I'm trying to search (using PHPStorm Regular Expressions aka- "regex") within a large codebase of multiple css/scss files to search only within brackets `{ css }`

Basically, I'm trying to find all instances of where any css element has 2 font-weights assigned to it, and overwrite it with just one.

For example:

```
.classname { font-weight: 100; color: blue; font-weight: 400; }
```

to replace with:

```
.classname { font-weight: 100; color: blue; }
```

But the font-weights are all different. And I need to only search within the brackets. I'm not very familiar with regex, but have used `(.*)` and `$1` to replace groups (wildcards) of code.

Also, there could be multiple lines & spaces to search through... so I'll need that taken into account for the regular expression.

```
.classname {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

I've tried `\{(.*)font-weight:(.*)font-weight:(.*)\}` and it only searches one single-line code.

In short...
How would I search for any CSS classname that has 2 font-weights assigned to it:

```
.classname1 {
    font-weight: anything;
    otherCSS: anything;
    moreCSS: anything;
    font-weight: anything;
}
```

Needs to be something like: `{ * font-weight:*; * font-weight:*; * }`
Where the * can be anything. Any number of spaces, any character, any line-break.

Comment: Do you want this? https://regex101.com/r/2PgW0N/1

Comment: What?! I didn't even know this regex101 site existed! Thanks @Mr.kang

Comment: Refer to https://regex101.com/r/9Bvra9/1 Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`(.*?\{\sfont-weight: 100;\s.*?;\s)(?:font-weight.*?)?(\})` will work for you.

You need to replace the entire string by `$1$2`.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/crbDS6/1)

Answer (score 1):

I have improved the regex of TheLostMind, so that the last attribute does not have to be font-weight.

`(.*?\{\sfont-weight: 100;\s.*?;\s)(?:font-weight:.*?;)?(.*\})`

Comment: Would'nt this match 'til the last curly bracket in the file, thus producing a wrong result?